# Git patchset-created hook get argument

Tags: git, gerrit

I am creating a patchset-created hook shell script. I am able to trigger a Jenkins job to run whenever I submit a new patch set to Gerrit server.

Now, I wish to get argument and pass to Jenkins job through curl command. I am not sure how to achieve this and I give some try but unluckily, I couldn't get the argument passed successfully.

Gerrit patchset-created hook parameter:

```
patchset-created --change <change id> --is-draft <boolean> --kind <change kind> --change-url <change url> --change-owner <change owner> --project <project name> --branch <branch> --topic <topic> --uploader <uploader> --commit <sha1> --patchset <patchset id>
```

My script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#trigger Jenkin job with API token 
curl -X POST http://<username>:<API token>@<server>/job/<job name>/build --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"change_id", "value":<change id value>}]}'
```

I would like to have the < change id > from Gerrit hook parameter pass to "value":< change id > and pass to Jenkins job through curl command. Anyone know how to get the argument?

Answer (score 0):

finally found a solution to get the arguments from Gerrit server and pass those arguments back to Jenkins job:

1. Get arguments from Gerrit server:

   ```
   CHANGE_ID=""
   CHANGE_URL=""
   PATCHSET=""

   while [ $# -gt 0 ]
   do
       case "$1" in
       "--change")
          CHANGE_ID=$2
          shift 2
          ;;
       "--change-url")
          CHANGE_URL=$2
          shift 2
          ;;
       "--patchset")
          PATCHSET=$2
          shift 2
          ;;
   *)
       shift
       ;;
      esac
   done
   ```